# htaccess redirect issue with pathname

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I have a pathname structure like this:

domainname.com/categoryname/*

I need to redirect them to 
domainname.com/newname/categoryname/*

This will not work, because this will create an infinite loop.
RewriteRule ^foldername(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/newname/categoryname$1 [R=301,L]

Note: The "categoryname" is not really a folder; it is part of a pathname using clean URLs. The "newname" is a new installation in a folder. I am removing only some items from the main installation in the root to the installation in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(?!newname)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ newname/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?!newname)` asserts that what follows is not `newname`, avoiding looping
- `([^/]+)` captures the category name to Group 1
- `/` matches a literal `/`
- `([^/]+)` matches the name
- `/?` matches an optional `/` at the end
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks. Give me a day or so. I'll revert.

Cheers!